# Syntax for requring csv-parse if it is a part of the csv package

Tags: node.js

this is probably just a simple gotcha, but I cannot figure out the syntax (new to node.js)

I have done a

```
npm install csv
```

in my node.js project. [The project's homepage can be found here](http://csv.adaltas.com/)

The following line runs without issue:

```
var csv = require('csv');
```

But when I need to use csv-parse functions ([which is a part of the csv package](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/)) I cannot. Trying to require it yields a not found:

```
var parse = require('csv-parse');
Error: Cannot find module 'csv-parse'
```

I've tried a few variations:

```
var parse = require('csv()csv-parse');
var parse = require('csv.csv-parse');
var parse = require('csv().csv-parse');
```

thinking they had to reference the csv bit required just above it, but none seem to work. I could always just re-install just the csv-parse bit, but the website indicates that I shouldn't need to (as either are enough):

*Run npm install csv to install the full CSV package or run npm install csv-parse if you are only interested by the CSV parser.*

But sadly I cannot find [any examples on the project page](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/examples/) that work with just installing 'csv'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its exported with `csv`, here's an example

```
var parse = require('csv').parse
```

As a note about requiring another modules dependencies: I have never found the need to do that, as most module authors, either export (as in this case) or provide a suitable abstraction. That said you could usually `require` a dependency of an installed module with the following form:

```
var dep = require('{module}/node_modules/{dependency}');
```

In this case:

```
var parse = require('csv/node_modules/csv-parse');
// require('csv').parse === require('csv/node_modules/csv-parse') -> true
```

But as I said, I have never had to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem with Node 8 (worked fine with Node 7). This worked for me:

Instead of installing the `csv` package as a dependency directly, install `csv-parse`. If you still need the `csv` package as well, install both.

```
"dependencies": {
  "csv": "^2",
  "csv-parse": "^2"
}
```

This is necessary if you want to use [the Synchronous API](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/) via `require('csv-parse/lib/sync')`

Answer (score 1):

A problem may likely exist with the version of npm you are using. We were using an older npm version (2.14.12) and after npm install csv, the dependent modules including csv-parse were placed within csv/node_modules/csv-parse instead of as peers as expected. When we upgraded to newer npm version (3.8.0) this fixed the issue after removing (npm uninstall csv) then running npm install csv again.

Comment: This answer is misleading or incorrect as far as I know. In Node you must *always* declare dependencies you intend to require directly in *your* `package.json`. Directory flattening optimizations are an implementation detail that you cannot and should not count on.